# Euclidean projection on convex set of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, symmetric-matrices, projection, positive-semidefinite

Define the Euclidean projection for a convex set $C$ as follows

$$\pi_C(y) := \min_{x \in C} \| y - x \|_2^2$$

How would we find the projection map when $C$ is the cone of positive semidefinite matrices, i.e., $\displaystyle C := \{ M : M \succeq 0 \}$?

---

I'm not really sure how to proceed since I can't really get a hold of how to think about how 'close' a non positive semidefinite matrix is to a positive semidefinite one.

Comment: I think this is a research argument

Comment: I mean, for symmetric matrices I think the answer is easy, but for general matrices it is not. Also, what kind of norm do you use?

Comment: Which $2$-norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty much the same, you can define for instance the distance

$$\pi_C(Y):=\min_{X\in C}||Y-X||_F^2$$

where $C:=\{X\in\mathbb{S}^n:X\succeq0\}$, and $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm defined as $||X||_F^2:=\mathrm{trace}(X^TX)$.

This can be cast as a semidefinite program of the form:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\underset{X}{\min} && \mathrm{trace}(A^TA-A^TX-XA+M)\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&& X\succeq0,\\
&&\begin{bmatrix}
M & X\\X & I
\end{bmatrix}\succeq0.
\end{array}$$